# Prompt Before Every Request with Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, breakpoints, developer-tools

Is it possible with the Google Chrome Developer Tools to pause before each request (css, javascript, images, etc) is made *similar to JavaScript breakpoints*?

For example:

```
GET http://example.com
PAUSE...
GET http://example.com/css/styles.css
PAUSE...
GET http://example.com/js/scripts.js
```

This could be useful to get the url of a request before it is executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with an extension. 
I've found this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb/related?hl=en.

See their README.me https://github.com/google/tamperchrome/blob/master/README.md for how to use it.

Basically once you've install the extension:

1. Go to developper console
2. Select Tamper panel
3. Check Block/Reroute requests
4. Reload your page and that's it

Tamper will block every requests one by one and ask you what to do with it ;)

Comment: There is an updated version of this extension called Tamper Dev, just FYI.

Comment: This no longer works if you want to modify the request body before sending the request.

Answer (score 13):

Chrome debugger actually has an XHR/fetch breakpoint checkbox on the sidepanel of the sources tab in the DevTools window. If you check it, it will actually pause on the function in the JavaScript script, and you can identify it in situe!

[image: Chrome DevTools with XHR/fetch breakpoint checkbox visible]